# find maximum of set of columns for multiple rows in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

I have a table with the following fields and data.

```
RefNo Year Month Code
1     2010  7     A
2     2009  10    B
3     2010  8     A
4     2010  5     B
```

From this i've to find out the maximum(year, month)  for a particular code.
The result must be

```
3   2010  8 A
1   2010  7 B
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Do you want to do this for every `Code` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC) AS row_number,
    *
  FROM
    myTable
)
  AS orderedTable
WHERE
  row_number = 1
```

**EDIT** And now for a version that WORKS in MySQL...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  Year * 12 + Month = (SELECT MAX(Year * 12 + Month) FROM myTable AS lookup WHERE Code = myTable.Code)
```

**EDIT** After access to SQL, can confirm this is faster...

```
WHERE
    Year  = (SELECT MAX(Year)  FROM myTable AS lookup WHERE Code = myTable.Code)
AND Month = (SELECT MAX(Month) FROM myTable AS lookup WHERE Code = myTable.Code AND Year = myTable.Year)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? The idea is to combine Year and Month into something that SQL can take the MAX of, then join the table to this modified version of itself.

```
SELECT OriginalTable.RefNo, OriginalTable.Year, OriginalTable.Month, OriginalTable.Code
FROM table OriginalTable,
     (SELECT Code, MAX(Year*100 + Month) AS CombinedDate
      FROM table
      GROUP BY Code) AS MaximumResults
WHERE OriginalTable.Code = MaximumResults.Code
AND OriginalTable.Year = MaximumResults.CombinedDate / 100
AND OriginalTable.Month = MaximumResults.CombinedDate % 100
```

The idea is explained more thoroughly here: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php

Comment: Nice. I think you forgot to to add the condition for `CombinedDate` (it must take part in the joining too, I understand). Also, why not use a currently standard syntax for join? Yours is outdated, even if it's working. I mean, you are offering your solution for others, after all.

Comment: Oh my, you are right -- there are a variety of problems here. Anyway, thanks for the constructive criticism; I'm kind of liking this place!

Answer (score 0):

Say your table name is "table1" then

```
select * from
(select * from table1 where Year in (select max(Year) from table1)) abc
where Month not in (select min(Month) from abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution:

```
Select Month(B.NewDate) Mon, Year(B.NewDate) Year, Code, PK
from T1 A ,
(Select Max(Str_To_Date(Concat('01',',',Month,',',Year), '%d,%m,%Y')) as NewDate, Code C
from T1 group by Code) B
Where PK = (Select PK from T1
                where Year = Year(B.NewDate) and Month = Month(B.NewDate)  and Code = A.Code)
and A.Code = C
group by Code
```