# Latest date with SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks in advance for assisting me. I have the following table:

```
 Name | LastUpdate  |   Amount  |
 ABC  |  2014-4-9   |    100    |
 ABC  |  2014-4-9   |  **101**  |
 ABC  |  2014-4-8   |     99    |
 DEF  |  2014-4-9   |  **200**  |
 DEF  |  2014-4-8   |    160    |
 GHI  |  2014-4-9   |   **50**  |
 GHI  |  2014-4-8   |     80    |
```

---

My queries doesn’t seems to work to get the following result: The sum of Amount for the latest date and highest amount for all names.

> Example answer for above is 351 (101+200+50).

Comment: but I see from the above example the result should be 100+101+200+50=451

Comment: what datatype is the LastUpdate-Column in SQL??

Comment: You have to use sub query but first you have to check your table data type.

Comment: And youe using what type of database (RDBMS)?

Comment: @user3470953 He only wants one amount per name, so not 100

Comment: Sorry I have edited the right answer which is 351, datatype of lastupdate is date, db is mysql

Comment: Yes correct I want only 1 answer which is the sum of the 3 names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I based this solution on the answer to

[find maximum of set of columns for multiple rows in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414147/find-maximum-of-set-of-columns-for-multiple-rows-in-mysql-query)

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM table1 AS t
WHERE LastUpdate = (SELECT MAX(LastUpdate) 
                    FROM table1 
                    WHERE NAme = t.Name)
AND Amount = (SELECT MAX(Amount) 
              FROM table1
              WHERE Name = t.Name
              AND LastUpdate = t.LastUpdate)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86c049/1)

Comment: OK it works when the latest date is the same (2014-4-9) for all names. However below doesnt work where GHIs max date is differentcreate table table1 (Name varchar(50),LastUpdate date,Amount int);

insert into table1 values('ABC','2014-4-9',100);
insert into table1 values('ABC','2014-4-9',101);
insert into table1 values('ABC','2014-4-8',99);
insert into table1 values('DEF','2014-4-9',200);
insert into table1 values('DEF','2014-4-8',160);
insert into table1 values('GHI','2014-4-6',50);
insert into table1 values('GHI','2014-4-5',80);

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you wanted the max date for each name, your example used the max date for everyone. I've posted a new query that should work for your clarification.

Comment: Bravo Barmar thats spot on!